# terminating subprocess after amount of time

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two binaries which are not terminating without pressing CTRLC-C on terminal. I call these binaries with subprocess call. But I want to terminate them after some amount of time. Here is what I try:

```
    cmd_1 = [**SOME COMMANDS**]
    cmd_2 = [**SOME COMMANDS**]
    commands = [cmd_1, cmd_2]
    procs = [Popen(i) for i in commands]
    for p in procs:
        time.sleep(60)
        p.kill();
```

But after 60 seconds, processes are still running. How can I terminate them after some amount of time?

Comment: BTW I deleted my answer because I found out that there were no `timeout` on `Popen` call..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first process will be killed after 60 seconds, the second will after 120. The time.sleep(60) should be outside the loop

```
cmd_1 = [**SOME COMMANDS**]
cmd_2 = [**SOME COMMANDS**]
commands = [cmd_1, cmd_2]
procs = [Popen(i) for i in commands]
time.sleep(60)
for p in procs:
    p.kill()
```

However, it is worth noting that that `**SOME COMMANDS**` could be causing further issue